# How to recover the deleted items in Google Drive?

Tags: shared-folders, google-drive, file-recovery

Is there a way to recover the deleted items `(which are shared with me)` in Google Drive? They are not in the trash even. A message appears just after the deletion mentioning `Undo' the action. So I clicked on undo button. But no files were recovered.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since they're shared, they should still exist in the file owner's Drive, correct?

Comment: Are you sure about it?

Answer (score 1):

Try visiting this url, it worked for me

```
https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/search?q=is:unorganized%20owner:me
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are viewing shared documents (someone is sharing documents with you) and you delete those docs off of your system they will still exist in the owners file drive and anyone else that has access to them. You will be able to regain access to files depending on how the sharing settings unique to that document (public on web, anyone with link, privately shared) have been set up. Good luck.